# Bash Counting within a folder

Tags: bash, file, counting

I need to count how many folders and files can be found in a folder.
Also for the files how many have full permission.

```
if [ -d $string ]
then
 ls -1 $string | wc -l
 grep "rwx" $string
 exit
fi
```

However this is not the correct way to do so

Comment: [`man find`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find) should be helpful. `find` can handle both of these tasks.

Comment: Please define "full permission". When you say "can be found in" do you want contents of subfolders?

Answer (score 0):

The following command would find all files with full permission in only the directory `$string`

```sh
find $string -maxdepth 1 -perm 777
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the amount of directories:

```
find ./ -type d | wc -l
```

Keep out: this includes the current directory too.

Find the amount of files:

```
find ./ -type f | wc -l
```

Obviously, when you don't have access to certain subdirectories, this might give wrong results.